# Bash Script to archive files into folders based on part of filenames

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have found examples of similar questions sorting files into folders based on the filename but don't really know where to start with this as i need to loop through multiple things and could do with some help please.

I have a folder of telephone recordings with the following file name format:

```
OUT260-20140828-125114-1409226674.42655.wav
```

it is split up into several parts

```
OUT260 = 260 is the name of the extension
20140828 = the date
125114 = the time
```

the rest im not sure I think it's some king of id because it increments each time.

what i want to end up with is the following folder stucture created by a cron job / bash script

top level

extension numbers eg

260, 261 ,262

then year
then month
then day
then multiple files eg for the file name above 260-1251.wav

so if this can be achieved the example file would end up as below

```
/Recordings/260/2014/08/28/260-1251.wav
```

i have the following example which is a more basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for full_filename in *jpg; do
extension="${full_filename##*.}"
filename="${full_filename%.*}"
mkdir -p "$filename/picture"
mv "$full_filename" "$filename/picture"
done
```

Hope that makes sense any help much appreciated

Comment: Does this mean everything starts with `OUT`?

Comment: There may be other files in the folder but the only ones I am looking to work with start with OUT yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do this is using `sed` to replace the name by the path:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in OUT*.jpg
do
    res=$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's#^OUT([0-9]+)\-([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{4}).*\.(.*)$#/Recordings/\1/\2/\3/\4/\1-\5.\6#g')
    mkdir -p `dirname "$res"`
    mv "$f" "$res"
done
```

For example if `$f` is `OUT260-20140828-125114-1409226674.42655.wav`, `$res` is `/Recordings/260/2014/08/28/260-1251.wav`. For filenames that don't follow the correct pattern, `$res` is the same as `$f` so nothing happens.

`sed` makes use of regular expression to find and replace (parts of) the filename. The syntax is somehow hard to explain but there are a lot of good tutorials on the internet.

Furthermore please note that it is in general not a good idea to use a root dir like `/Recordings``...

Please use `cp` first for testing...

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response.  It looks as though its going to work but it is saying:   cannot move `OUT260-20140827-154225-1409150545.40620.wav' to `/home/Recordings/260/2014/08/27/260-1542.wav': No such file or directory
Is there a way to create the destination folders if they don't exist at the same time.

Comment: @Ross: I modified the program, if you add the `mkdir -p` line, it will work. Althoug as commented, perhaps you better first try with `cp` since this protects one from data loss :s.

Comment: Fantastic this is perfect, thanks very much.  I had changed the back ticks for single quotes as thought it was a copy paste error.

Comment: No, backticks are used to inline another function. The `bash` environment will thus first calculate `dirname "$res"` and then substitute this into `mkdir -p`

Comment: It works brilliant. I'm going to read up on this sed function and regular expressions.  Thanks again